# ApexCRUDviolation Fix

Tags: apex, crud, pmd, inner

How to fix ApexCRUDViolation for inner query. Below is the query.

`proposal = [select Id, Name,(Select Id From PQConfig__Configurations__r) From Proposal__Proposal__c Where Proposal__Opportunity__c =:lead.ConvertedOpportunityId];`

I tried the below one to fix the violation. Violation is fixed.

```
if(!Schema.sObjectType.Proposal__Proposal__c.isQueryable() && !Schema.sObjectType.PQConfig__Configurations__r.isAccessible()) {
 return null;
 }
```

But, PQConfig__Configurations__r is not an object. Getting error while saving class in Salesforce. Please help me to fix the violation.

Comment: 'PQConfig__Configurations__r' is a child relationship name and not Object name, you will have to find the object's API name and then check for violation on that sObject.

Comment: I tried with object API name but still getting the same violation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
if(Schema.sObjectType.Proposal__Proposal__c.isQueryable()){

   proposal = Database.query('select Id, Name,(Select Id From PQConfig__Configurations__r) From Proposal__Proposal__c Where Proposal__Opportunity__c =:lead.ConvertedOpportunityId');

}
```

So the PMD will pass the validation for the parent Sobject.